# How can I show a value in a javascript onchange?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I did an app in rails using javascript to do a sum.

But I have a problem when my value is nil or empty won't work and shows "NaN".

Could be a way to fix this or maybe show " 0 " insteaf of "NaN"?

Here is my controller

```
 def
   @soles = Client.sum(:money)
 end
```

The problem is when @soles is nil , I need a way to show 0.

```
 <input type="text" id="my_input1" value="<%=  @soles  %>" />
 <input type="text" id="my_input2" onchange="doMath();" />
 <input type="text" id="sum" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
function doMath()
{
    // Capture the entered values of two input boxes
    var my_input1 = document.getElementById('my_input1').value;
    var my_input2 = document.getElementById('my_input2').value;

    // Add them together and display
    var sum = parseInt(my_input1) + parseInt(my_input2);
    document.getElementById('sum').value = sum;
}
```

I tried but doesn't work

```
@soles = 0
```

I will really appreciate help.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [isNaN](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp) javascript function like this :

```
if (isNaN(sum))
    sum = 0;
document.getElementById('sum').value = sum;
```

Comment: i tried your code but now is showing 0 when it has value

Comment: Ok thanks that's great but can you help me to show 0 when doesn't have value my_input1 ? http://jsfiddle.net/nu7z5/2/

Comment: @CarlitosMorales Ok, look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nu7z5/3/). I made several explanations inside this fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this

```
if(!document.getElementById("yourElementIDName")){

  alert("DOES NOT EXIST");

} 

else {

    alert("Object Exists - You can script to this object");

}
```